# Clogit and no variation in strata

Tags: r, fixed-effects-model, clogit

Suppose that I want to identify a causal effect with panel data. The dependent variable is dichotomous so I use a conditional logit with `survival::clogit` in R, with clusters for each individual. If an individual is always treated, my understanding is that the fixed effects model drops the observation. But how do I see how many observations are dropped? In the regression output I do not get any information on this (and the number of observations equals the number of rows in my dataframe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the `clogit` function in the `survival` package, strata with no variation in the predictor are *not* dropped; they just end up not contributing any information to the estimator.  The function does not keep track of which strata contribute information, so if you want to know how many strata have variation in a particular variable you'll have to just compute that directly from the data.

Comment: Yes, I mean `survival::clogit`; thank you!